# How to concatenate variable values in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a value that can come from one of two places (arg or header), and I'm keen to extract it into a single place.

I've tried to basically do a few variations on the following:

```
set $normalized "$http_value$arg_value";
if ($normalized ~ /(regex_im_looking_for)/) {
   set $truevalue $1;
}
```

but these all yield syntax errors. Is there a canonical way to concatenate values? Is there a better way to do what I'm looking to do here? It feels like this should be fairly simple.

Comment: What errors did you receive?

Comment: Did you try `set $normalized "${http_value}${arg_value}";`

Comment: Instead of using `if`, you should look into using `map`. It is faster and more reliable.